# Title tag wont change

Tags: bug, wp-error

I changed the Title of the Blog, in the Customizer and everywhere else i checked the title, it changed, except on the actual site.
I already checked, if the tag is set static in the header.php, its not.

The theme is: Hemingway

The WP Version is: 4.7.7(Will update to 4.9 soon)

PHP: 7.0.25

Regards Liz3

Comment: is it all pages or just the homepage.  it maybe basing off the page title.

Answer (score 0):

see there are any upgrade available for the theme.. if not add

```
add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
```

in your functions.php